# How to create something like Expander control in WPF using only WinAPI (ATL/WTL)?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-controls, wtl

I am newbie in English, sorry :) 
How to create something like Expander control in WPF using only WinAPI (ATL/WTL)? Are some experince avaliable?
Thank for answers!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the Expander control looks but there is a good collection of WTL widgets available [here](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/all_wtl.htm).  It might get you started - there is some very cool code available.

Comment: Thank for the link, it is very useful for me.
I've decided to write this control from scratch :)

Answer (score 0):

You can build something rather similar from `WTL::CPaneContainerImpl<>` (in *atlctrlx.h*). Not ready out of the box though.